# CALayer Live Resize Poor Performance

Tags: macos, calayer, catransaction

I have a UI where the content of an `NSCollectionViewItem`'s View is drawn programmatically through CALayers. I am using a `CAConstraintLayoutManager` to keep the layot of the sublayers consistent when resizing, but I am getting very poor performance when doing so. It seems that resizing the window, which causes the resize of two `CATextLayer`s so that they fit the root layer's width, and the repositioning of one `CATextLayer` so that it stays right-aligned, is causing the application to spend most of its time executing the `CGSScanConvolveAndIntegrateRGB` function (I have used the Time Profiler instrument).

The most "expensive" layer (the one that causes the most stuttering even if it's the only one displayed) is a wrapped multiline `CATextLayer`. I have absolutely no idea how to get better performance (I have tried not using a `CAConstraintLayoutManager` and going with layer alignments but I'm getting the same thing). Has anyone had this problem? Is there a way around it?

PS: I have subclassed the layout manager and disabled all the animations during the execution of `- (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer` by setting YES to `kCATransactionDisableActions` in the `CATransaction` but it doesn't seems to help.

**Edit:** I have disabled Font Smoothing for the Text Layers and performance has increased a little bit (very little), but it spends an awful amount of time in _ZL9view_drawP7_CAViewdPK11CVTimeStampb (which is something that gets called by a thread of the ATI Radeon driver, I suppose).

Comment: It turns out that I was resizing ALL the views and not only the ones that were visible inside the ScrollView's visible rect. I am implementing a way to resize only the visible views because, as far as I can tell, there is no built in way to do that and it's not the default behavior. Go figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Kind of. It still seems like a dirty hack to me, but I couldn't find out how to make `setNeedsDisplayInRect` work so I ended up doing it like this:

1. In the NSWindow delegate:

   -(void)windowWillStartLiveResize:(NSNotification *)notification 
   {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"beginResize" object:nil];
   }

   -(void)windowDidEndLiveResize:(NSNotification *)notification 
   {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"endResize" object:nil];
   }
2. In my Custom View those two notifications call, respectively, the `-(void)beginResize` and `-(void)endResize` selectors. The first one sets a BOOL inLiveResize variable to YES, while the second one sets it to NO and calls setFrameSize again with the new frame size.
3. I overrode (overridden? Not native english speaker, sorry) the `-(void)setFrameSize:(NSSize)newSize` method like this:

   ```
   -(void)setFrameSize:(NSSize)newSize 
   {        
       if (inLiveResize) {
           NSRect scrollFrame = [[[self superview] enclosingScrollView] documentVisibleRect];

           BOOL condition1 = (self.frame.origin.y > (scrollFrame.origin.y - self.frame.size.height));
           BOOL condition2 = (self.frame.origin.y < (scrollFrame.origin.y + scrollFrame.size.height + self.frame.size.height));

           if (condition1 && condition2)
               [super setFrameSize:newSize];
       }
       else {
           [super setFrameSize:newSize]; }}
   ```

That's it. This way, only the visible views resize live with the window, while the others get redrawn at the end of the operation. It works, but I don't like how 'dirty' it is, I'm sure there is a more elegant, built-in(ish) way to do this by using the `setNeedsDisplayInRect` method. I will research more.